# UV Mapping a modified Cylinder

Tags: uv

Create a cylinder with NoCaps.

In the Top View, select all faces, Mesh -> Extrude -> Extrude Faces Along Normals

to get a shape like so:

[image: Extruded Faces]

Applied all Transformations in Object mode CtrlA -> All Transformations

Apply a checkered map like so:

[image: Apply Map]

[image: Distortions]

To fix the shown parts and others, added Seams like so:

[image: Seams]

Select all faces UV -> Unwrap

[image: Unwrap]

The distortion is still the same.
Tried with other seams and changing Unwrap from Angle to Conformal with no affect.

Any clues on how to go about fixing this?

Appreciate any help.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default your material uses auto generated UVs. To use your manually created UVs you must change the input vector to UV map instead of Generated.